# Limiting input voltage for buck converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, battery-operated, step-down

I want to power some micro controllers and a couple of leds on my electric bike, counting up towards 5 Amps.

Power supply is a 36V battery, with a range of about 42V to 33V. This voltage is to be brought back to 7V for LEDs and then further down to 5V with a LM317 for Attinies, Arduino and SIM 800.

Most of the buck converters I come accross are rated up to 40V. So with a full battery I exceed this value. I have mounted some five bucks now and they got all fried, I'm affraid.

**Edit**: the schematis of a LM2596 (which most of the blown ones were) typical usage:

[image: LM2596ADJ, source Texas Instruments]

I see 2 possible solutions, and ask you guys please to consider what to do (or add a much better idea!):

1. Limit the input voltage by a divider
2. Replace capacitors (and inductor) on the boards

@1: Which power rating the resistors should have to make sure these 5 amps are available for the buck? How to prevent an enormous draw from battery?

@2: Does anybody have any idea on whether this is doable at all? If I look at the datasheet of TI LM 2596; caps and coil are critical choices for eventual power of the design. Messing around with the original ones might get me into trouble?

Thnx for any direction in this, and please bare with me since I'm quitte novice in all this.

Comment: Since it is a bike and it sounds like efficiency might not be an issue? If you hop on over to [mouser](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Power-Management-ICs/Voltage-Regulators-Voltage-Controllers/Linear-Voltage-Regulators/_/N-5cg9g) you can search for linear regulators that can take up to 100V and shift down to 5V. Again, efficiency out the window, but if you just want functionality, maybe try that?

Comment: A schematic or block diagram might be helpful. It will be easier to see what you're trying to accomplish. Also, a quick search shows the MIC28514 Buck Converter. Would this work out?

Comment: Here's an example of a linear regulator that can take 125V and deliver 5V, [a TL783 high-voltage regulator from Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl783.pdf?ts=1588092154045)

Comment: @PeterT he wants 5 amps according to the opening line of the question and NO, efficiency is likely to be a BIG issue.

Comment: If you can source try these TPS54561,TPS54560B( I recommend this) from TI, L4970A from ST micro,RTQ6365 from Richtek,  TN5D51A  from Sanyo. If you are OK with Buck controllers(With external MOSFETs) you have more options.

Comment: If you could change your design so that the LEDs can be power from 12V, then a part like this can work https://www.droking.com/120W-Car-Adapter-DC-60V(20V-72V)-to-12V-10A-120W-Buck-Converter-Power-Supply-Module-Voltage-Regulator-Driver-Module-Waterproof?search=buck%20converter&description=true

Comment: @PeterT thanks for your suggestion TL783, but what Andy already said: I need some 5 A and this IC goes up to about 700 mA. And efficiency is an issue; I don't want to drain the battery. I'm about to check other suggestions (tnhx bros!) and I'll edit my question adding a shematic of the LM2596, which is the buck concerter that I use until now.

Comment: @Jay I edited my post with a schematic, although is a generic one. TI offers a great service online (https://webench.ti.com/power-designer), which I prefer to use to avoid any erratic setup of components/values. The MIC your suggesting might be convenient, but I'm too unexperienced in both designing, milling and soldering to use chips with this footprint. I can handle external pins in ICs up to SOIC(8) in my PCBs.

Comment: @user19579 TPS54560B looks very convenient, but also very complicated at first glance. Why do you reccomand this above other possibilities?

Comment: @Leoman12 very usefull tip. I wouldn't have to change the voltage of LEDs, I can simply use your suggestion to feed all subsequent converters in my bike for their needed voltages. This comes close to 'the voltage divider' that I had in mind in my original question. Thanks!

Comment: Whether you have designed any Buck's previously. complexity depends on your experience. why i suggested TPS54650B/TPS54561 is they have flexible options in terms of variable switching frequency which helps in optimizing size of the solution for different parameters, current mode control, good protection methods.

Comment: @user19579: when I might get old and wise I hope I will remember this suggestion of yours and being able to play with these parameters. Your motivation seems very valuable!

Comment: @user9303562: I don't know if my words de motivated you or hurt you.. But those IC's suggested are generic Buck controllers. When you say they are complex - i don't really understand where they are complex - I don't know your capabilities/skills similarly you maynot mine also. I am sorry if hurt you.... But for me those are not complex. Remember one thing working now may not guarantee that same will work after 6 months or more.I have seen people more time/money after few months if they select some poor components. If you need good converters for your application, then suggested one's are good.

Comment: @user19579 no problemo: no demotivation nor been hurt. Your ICs are complicated in a way that I don't fully understand all the data available in the datasheets. I'll have to evoluate before trully understand it. As I said, I'm still quitte novice to electronics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be that you can't find DC-DC converters that accept more than +40V input.  There are in fact many such devices (either chips or modules).

Here is one example.
DC DC CONVERTER VIN = 5.5V to 50V, VOUT=5.0V, 28W 
https://www.pololu.com/product-info-merged/4091
You can buy it at Digikey for $20.
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/pololu-corporation/4091/2183-4091-ND/11586858

Here is another example
DC DC CONVERTER VIN=9V to 53V, VOUT = 3.3V TO 16.5V, 8A, 128W
https://product.tdk.com/info/en/documents/spec/dc-dc-converter/i3a_spec.pdf?ref_disty=digikey
I3A4W008A033V-001-R
You can buy it at Digikey for $22.74
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tdk-lambda-americas-inc/I3A4W008A033V-001-R/285-2720-ND/7321113

If you want an DC-DC converter IC the LTC3895 can accept up to +150V DC input.

Additionally, Linear Tech/Analog Devices has a product line called a "Surge Stopper".

Finally you an use a 40V zener diode and power BJT to make the equivalent of a linear regulator that would effectively limit the input voltage if you choose to use a 40V converter.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks everybody for your inputs.

What I did eventually is a derivate of the suggestion of @PeterT:

I downgraded the input a few volts to 35V with a LM317 (I had in stock).
This setup has had its endurance test: 24 hours on without any noticeble side-effects.

Might my buckconverter nevertheless get fried again, I will defenitely go for the Pololu: what a marvelous designed beauty that is! Thanx @user4574 for this suggestion, I'll check your answer as being most usefull for the long term.

EDIT:

The buck was fried again. I pulled the 317 and the buck from their molten housing today and replaced the setup with a very straightforward solution that you can find [here](https://makingcircuits.com/blog/high-current-lm317-variable-power-supply-circuit/).

It is based on a high-current transistor (2N3055) that has been mounted in the emitter follower config. I'm not yet fully aware of how it works exactly, but it seems to work well!